# Difference between permutations p-value and Z-score p-value

Tags: p-value, permutation-test, z-score

I was asked to find a p-value for difference in means of a given data using 1,000,000 permutations and p-value using z-score of 1,000 permutations. In the beginning I received different results and tried to explain this, thought it has to do with CI of the permutations. However, after a long search I understand it is supposed to be pretty much the same. So why is it not?

```
#data
dfg <- data.frame( value = c(1.253105 ,0.5546414 ,0.301283 ,1.293125 ,0.9945558 ,0.5141743 ,2.007832 ,0.4222424 ,2.178773 ,3.217789 ,0.5578294 ,0.5946176 ,0.9773958 ,0.2098666 ,0.3094479 ,1.105936 ,0.7741878 ,0.08967408 ,1.108177 ,0.2472642 ,1.571987 ,4.832813 ,0.4311321 ,2.730389 ,1.136831 ,0.8133683 ,0.8370065 ,1.784765 ,2.312472 ,2.909887 ,2.949289 ,0.7030288 ,0.6901626 ,1.25069 ,0.4364978 ,0.2246223 ,0.3923198 ,1.576343 ,0.4279284 ,0.1960803 ,0.3772437 ,0.07071508 ,0.03962611 ,0.3858083 ,2.639289 ,0.7822081 ,0.664542 ,0.9568569 ,0.02484568 ,0.2160068 ,0.8803119 ,0.1356736 ,0.6818173 ,0.2011606 ,0.4834762 ,0.5010285 ,0.156685 ,0.7199208 ,0.6854979 ,0.8615078),
group = as.factor( c( rep('A', 30), rep('B', 30) ) ))

#true difference of means
true_diff <- mean(dfg$value[dfg$group =="A"]) - mean(dfg$value[dfg$group =="B"])

#1,000,000 permutations and p-value
permute_order <- replicate(1000000, sample(nrow(dfg)))
per_means <- data.frame(t(apply(permute_order,2,
                   function(new_order) tapply(dfg[new_order,1],
                                              dfg[,2],mean))))
res <- per_means$A - per_means$B
p <- (1 + sum(res>true_diff))/ 1000000

#1,000 permutaitons and p-value from z-score
permute_order <- replicate(1000, sample(nrow(dfg)))
per_means <- data.frame(t(apply(permute_order,2,
                   function(new_order) tapply(dfg[new_order,1],
                                              dfg[,2],mean))))
res2 <- per_means$A - per_means$B
z <- (true_diff - mean(res2))/sd(res2)
pz <- pnorm(q=z, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

And got p = 0.005902~
pz = 0.007476512

Even when I calculate p-value from the Z-score of the 1,000,000 permutations I get something close to pz. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: The computation with the z-score fits a normal distribution to your permutations and uses that fit to compute a p-value. That will give a different result when your data is not normal distributed.

Comment: As an extreme example use `dfg$value <- c(rep(0,59),1)`. This will make the `res` variable  have only the values of $\pm 1$.

Comment: I imagine that there are already some questions and answers that go into this topic.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching but couldn't find. However, I run shapiro.test in R and got p < 0.05 and assumed I can consider a normal distribution of the data.

Comment: A smaller p-value means a larger discrepancy from a normal distribution. So your p-value being below 0.05 does not support the idea that the data is normal distributed and does actually the opposite. (It may be criticized whether these tests are a lot relevant, but in anyway, relevant or irrelevant, the p-value is no indication to consider the data to be normal distributed).

Comment: Cannot believe I made this mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, doesn't permutations make the mean results have a normal distribution?
So if I check number of cases extreme as true difference for p value, and how my true difference fairs with the rest of mean difference results, the  z-score should still be good no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146790/discussion-between-zeev-and-sextus-empiricus).